# android.os.Parcelable android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, parcelable

i wanna pass the data, in the first fragment

```
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                progress = DetailProgressFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getProgress();
                bundle.putParcelable("progress", progress);
                new DetailProgressFragment().setArguments(bundle);

                Log.d("testProgress", String.valueOf(progress.getProgress_id()));

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, new DetailProgressFragment()).commit();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

second fragment

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        progress = (Progress) bundle.getParcelable("progress");
```

Error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: where do you call this `Bundle bundle = getArguments();`? It should be called after `onCreate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created two instance of your fragment. You should create only one like this.
Basically you receive NullPointerException because you put inside replace() a new instance of fragment without bundle data inside

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
progress = DetailProgressFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getProgress();
bundle.putParcelable("progress", progress);
DetailProgressFragment myFragment = new DetailProgressFragment();
myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
Log.d("testProgress", String.valueOf(progress.getProgress_id()));

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,myFragment).commit();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```